# How do I include a Keypress event inside a TextChanged event?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, keypress, textchanged

First up - I am a student and this is a project for my Capstone.  I don't want code as an answer just need a guide out of this forest.

I am writing a VB.Net app that includes a main form and secondary forms.  On the main form are controls (buttons and Textboxes) used to enter information (email and password.  in other words, a Login screen), I am using a textchanged sub to know when inforation is entered in the text box and attempting to use the Keypress to limit what is input. This is not working as I want.  I spent yesterday researching and trying different approaches. Only confused myself more.  Need some advice, please.

Bottom line is -- as a stand alone sub the keypress works very well but the button click does not operated as expected.  When I make the keypress part of the textchanged sub it all goes south instantly. I receive cast exceptions but no error code or other indication of what exactly went wrong.

My preferred is to have the keypress in the textchanged sub.
I want the textchenged sub to listen for the textbox to be changed and then be controlled by the keypress.

What am I doing wrong?

This sub does NOT operate as I think it should....

```
Private Sub txtemailid_TextChanged(ByVal o As [Object], ByVal e1 As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtemailid.TextChanged
    'Dim ac As String = "@"


    If e.KeyChar <> ChrW(Keys.Back) Then
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 97 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 122 Then
            If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 46 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 95 Then
                If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
                    If ac.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1 Then
                        e.Handled = True
                    Else
                        If txtemailid.Text.Contains("@") And e.KeyChar = "@" Then
                            e.Handled = True
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

The following sub works very well but interferes with the button controls on the form....

```
Private Sub txtemailid_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtemailid.KeyPress

  '*   Method   txtemailid_KeyPress()
  '*   Version:  1.00.00
  '*   Author:   Ed Petry
  '*   Date:     March-2, 2017
  '*
  '*   Description:
  '*   Intercepts the key presses as entered, allowing only acceptable characters to be entered.    
    '*    code will only allow user To input a-z(small), 0 To 9(digits), @,., 

    Dim ac As String = "@"

    If e.KeyChar <> ChrW(Keys.Back) Then
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 97 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 122 Then
            If Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 46 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <> 95 Then
                If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
                    If ac.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1 Then
                        e.Handled = True
                    Else
                        If txtemailid.Text.Contains("@") And e.KeyChar = "@" Then
                            e.Handled = True
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Additional explanation below

Yes, capitol letters are allowed but the instructor is 'ok' with demanding lower case only.

Here is the typical button sub routine (I have 'submit', 'clear form' and cancel' for the stated function. In addition, the form has 'create account' and ' forgot password' buttons.  These buttons lead to singleton design forms to allow for that feature (create or recover).

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click


    '*   Method:   btnSubmit_Click
    '*   Version:  1.00.00
    '*   Author:   Ed Petry
    '*   Date:     February-23, 2017
    '*
    '*   Description:
    '*   Intercept user's request to submit information in attempt to login.  

    '** MAY KEEP THIS MAY NOT  Throw up a Message Box to confirm that's what the operator
    '** MAY KEEP THIS MAY NOT   wants to do.  If so, cancel the login attempt and return to the initial state.
    Try

        ' try is placeholder to verify logic is correct.

        If MsgBox("Is your information correct?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

            ' Submit username and password informtion to business layer for verification of membership

        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        '  An error occured!  Show the error to the user and then exit.
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Additional comment---

This is the validating sub I am using after the information is input.  This works well..

```
'     uses validating event of textbox control to validate the email id using regular expression

Private Sub txtemailAddress_Validating(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles txtEmailAddress.Validating

    Dim pattern As String = "^[A-Z][A-Z|0-9|]*[a-z][a-z|0-9|]*([_][a-z|0-9]+)*([.][a-z|0-9]+([_][a-z|0-9]+)*)?@[a-z][a-z|0-9|]*\.([a-z][a-z|0-9]*(\.[a-z][a-z|0-9]*)?)$"

    Dim match As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(txtEmailAddress.Text.Trim(), pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    If (match.Success) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Success", "Checking")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid email address", "Checking")

        With txtEmailAddress
            .Clear()
            .Focus()
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't handle key presses in `TextChanged` for the obvious reason that `KeyPress` ≠ `TextChanged`. The `InvalidCastException` is thrown because the event args are of incorrect type for `TextChanged`. Could you explain further why you think you need this code in the `TextChanged` event as well?

Comment: You can only use the keypress for that. The textchanged event does not do KeyPressEventArgs and happens at an entirely different point in the sequence. You will have to edit your question to describe the "button" part since there is no code for that here.

Comment: Consider using [**regular expressions**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf(v=vs.110).aspx) to verify the e-mail address. Also, note that capital/uppercase letters [_**can be used in e-mail addresses**_](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34056/is-it-ok-to-use-uppercase-letters-in-email-address). Although it is discouraged for SMTPs to enforce case sensitivity, you should probably still allow them to use uppercase letters in case anyone's e-mail actually contains such.

Comment: @VisualVincent and a whole bunch of other punctuation marks... I had an O'Brady@Somewhere.Com once... That little unexpected quote caused all kinds of problems... LOL

Comment: @Trevor : ...which the Regex will solve. :)

Comment: Related: [Arrow Anti Pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrowAntiPattern) and of course [Coding Horror](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/).  It is easier, faster, better to just validate data entry than to try to police user actions at the keystroke level

Comment: That new piece of code you posted (the validation code), was it what solved your problem or was it already there when you asked the question? If it was what solved your problem then you should post it as an answer instead and accept it in 46 hours (self-answered questions can only be marked as answered 48 hours after asking the question).

Comment: @Visual Vincent -- validation code was present when original question asked.  I verified when the submit button was pressed.  I still have the issue of verifying input as the text is changed.  (But may abandon that approach and take my lumps on the grade). Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Must you validate it in real-time then? The Regex code can be used in the `TextChanged` event as well (put it into a function that returns `True` or `False`). Whenever the input is invalid just have it display a message box.

Comment: It is much harder to filter bad characters when you can paste in the text box, so you might want to just display a message.

Comment: Hi, Problem is resolved by following Visual Vincent's advice above.  I installed the Regex code in the submit button click and will live with that.  That strategy works and does not create issues elsewhere. How do I close this?  What is the procedure?

Comment: Hi everyone,     Thanks for the help.  I have decided to abandon including the keypress inside a textchanged. Greatly appreciate everyone's help and advice.Ed